# El significado de "carrera" en Consulado de Carrera de México

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Quisiera preguntar el significado de "carrera" en "[Consulado de Carrera de México](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/kansascity/)".

¿Tiene algo que ver con "[Profesión o actividad que exige una formación académica previa y, generalmente, la superación de un concurso público para acceder a aquella.](http://Profesi%C3%B3n%20o%20actividad%20que%20exige%20una%20formaci%C3%B3n%20acad%C3%A9mica%20previa%20y,%20generalmente,%20la%20superaci%C3%B3n%20de%20un%20concurso%20p%C3%BAblico%20para%20acceder%20a%20aquella.)", que es la definición número 7 en RAE?

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Mexico also seems to have _consulados generales_ so perhaps this is a less important rank?

Answer (score 1):

### Consulado

> Representación Permanente que mantiene un Estado en otro con el fin primordial de proteger y auxiliar a sus nacionales y fomentar las relaciones comerciales. El término designa a un mismo tiempo el órgano y su sede. Hay **Consulados de Carrera** y **Consulados Honorarios**, según que ejerzan todas las funciones consulares que permite el derecho internacional o se limiten al ejercicio de funciones secundarias.

<sub>*Fuente [protocoloimep.com](https://www.protocoloimep.com/diplomacia-publica/10-terminos-diplomaticos-que-debes-conocer/)*</sub>

De lo que se deduce:

**Consulado de carrera**: el consulado que ejerce todas las funciones que permite el derecho internacional.

**Cónsul de carrera**: El que por estar al frente de un Consulado de
Carrera tiene competencia para ejercer en su plenitud todas las funciones consulares que permite el Derecho internacional.

<sub>*Fuente [exteriores.gob.es](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Portal/es/Ministerio/Documents/T%C3%89RMINOS%20DIPLOM%C3%81TICOS.pdf)*</sub>